# Do cudaBindTextureToArray and cudaUnbindTexture break GPU-CPU concurrency?

Tags: cuda

I want my CPU and GPU to overlap computation, however, my GPU code contains some synchronous function calls like `cudaBindTextureToArray()` and `cudaUnbindTexture()` for which no asynchronous counterparts exists. Will these calls calls break GPU-CPU concurrency?

Comment: Where in the cuda program guide can I find a reference on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the functions that may be asynchronous are listed [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution):

```
  - •Kernel launches;
  - •Memory copies between two addresses to the same device memory;
  - •Memory copies from host to device of a memory block of 64 KB or less;
  - •Memory copies performed by functions that are suffixed with Async;
  - •Memory set function calls.
```

Asynchronous functions usually have an `Async` suffix, and they will usually accept a `stream` parameter.

Functions that don't meet the above description should be assumed to be synchronous.  Specific exceptions (like `cudaSetDevice()`) are usually evident from their description.

In the context of a single-device system, synchronous functions (with the exception of specific stream synchronizing functions like `cudaStreamSynchronize` and `cudaStreamWaitEvent`) will:

1. Wait to begin until *all cuda activity*  has completed (i.e. all previous cuda API calls and kernel calls have completed)
2. Execute their designated activity (e.g. `cudaMemcpy()` will begin the designated copy operation *after step 1 is complete*)
3. Release the calling (host) thread after step 2 is complete

Therefore the calling (host) thread is *blocked* from the moment the `cudaMemcpy()` call is made until all previous cuda activity is complete *and* the `cudaMemcpy()` call is complete.  I think most people would say this may "break" GPU-CPU concurrency, because for the duration of the sequence described above (steps 1-3) the CPU thread is effectively doing nothing.

Whether or not it makes much difference in your application will depend on what is happening before and after the synchronous call in question.